# Gylphicon not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

If I use this markup:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-vertical"></span>
```

the icon displays fine.
However, if I use this css rule:

```
.section-header::after {
    content:"\e119";
    float: right;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

it just displays the generic missing font square image.

Searching on the web it looks like other people have a similar issue but those seem to be resolved by correcting the location of the glyph-icon font files, however mine is in completely the right place, i.e. relative to the css it is at `..\fonts\`

What else might the problem be?

Comment: Define font family: Glyphicons Halflings

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Thanks

Comment: just posted the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `font-family`, try the following `CSS`, it should work

```
.section-header::after {
   content:"\e119";
   float: right;
   padding-left: 1em;
   font family: Glyphicons Halflings;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add font-family like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chetfarley/WK3Q6/1/)**

```
.section-header::after {
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content:"\e119";
    float: right;
    padding-left: 1em;

}
```